# How to identify an object created with raphael.js?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm using raphel library for creating a svg with images on it.
i need to get to the objects and change the image. i can get it using array index but i want to use the object id.

```
var R = Raphael("drawing","300", "300"),
c = [ { id:"obj1",obj: R.image("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-3d-glossy-interface-icon-set/64/Options.png", 0, 0, 50, 50)} ,
     {id:"obj2",obj: R.image("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-3d-glossy-interface-icon-set/64/Options.png", 100, 100, 50, 50)} ] ;
 move = function(dx,dy){
 this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});
},
start = function(){
this.ox = this.attr("x");
this.oy = this.attr("y");
this.animate({r: 70, opacity: .25}, 500, ">");
},
 up =function(){
this.animate({r: 50, opacity: 1}, 500, ">");
};

R.set(c).drag(move,start,up);

c[0].obj.attr("src","https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-3d-glossy-interface-icon-set/64/Circulation.png")
```

Comment: The following answer should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17050340/463205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c[0].node.setAttribute("id", "id_name");
```